# Single word for "winner takes all"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for the phrase "winner-take(s) all"?
Need to mention a single word heading for a issue within a Business report, explaining how a new technology release would mean winner takes all.

Answer (score 0):

You can say " a new technology release would mean a **tamed market**"  or " a new technology release would mean **monopoly**."